# Dividing ISP access for all computers in LAN

Tags: networking

My family had bought an old internet cafe with 18 computers connected to four(4) internet service provider (ISP) 3 routers and 1 modem, one 16 port desktop switch and 8 port ethernet switch to create an lan for games.

It was already configured by a tech before that cannot be contacted now but my brother had reseted all the routers and modem to factory default because he wanted to access its log-in page and that started our lan configuration problem.

All computers now can access internet but I cannot configure which router a certain computer was using, I had tried to check by accessing the ISP IP address "myipaddress.com" but it changes upon reboot, and for worst sometimes all computers were just using the modem and all 3 routers was not.

All we need to configure is like PC 1 to PC 5 will be assigned to use Router 1, PC 6 to 9 will use Router 2 and so on...

We would appreciate anyone that could help us as we were just starting on this small family business. Thank you...

[image]

Comment: This question in it's current form doesn't fit well with Server Fault or other question and answer sites because it's scope is too broad and would lead to too many follow up questions. I strongly suggest you call in an expert.  18 PC's is enough computers that you may need ongoing support.  Get someone in who actually knows what they are doing to support you.  You shouldn't need 4 ISP's for such a tiny LAN for starters.  Clearly the last guy didn't know what he was doing either to be set up like this.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute easiest way if the groups of computers do not need to communicate with *each other* is to buy a couple more switches and attach one switch to each router. Do not interconnect the switches with each other. Attach the computers to the switch connected to the router you want to use.

If you want to retain a network where all the machines are reachable from each other on the LAN side, you will probably need to implement a manual IP addressing scheme where you configure everything onto one subnet: give each router its own IP address (in that subnet) on its LAN (inside) interface. For each PC, set static IP addressing and set the default gateway to the address of the router you want it to use.

Turn off DHCP on all the routers. In theory you could use still use DHCP with a suitably sophisticated DHCP server (that could give different clients different gateway addresses), but I don't think you'll find that on a consumer grade router.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting a machine with 5 network cards/ports and installing [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/). (You can just add [one of these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P0NX3G) to a normal computer, though a real server would be a good idea).

The base software is free, but you'll want to get the subscription to their WAN Balancer app. This will let you designate 4 of the network ports as "external", and connect one ISP to each port. The remaining port will be for "internal" use. Connect that to your 16 port switch, and your workstations will all share internet access among the four ISPs.

You won't know which ISP a given computer is using at a given moment, but it *won't matter* because Untangle will balance between them automatically. The other trick here is that you'll want to set your ISP routers/modems all in bridge mode if you can, so that Untangle can handle all of the network routing without any double-NAT issues.

You may also find it worthwhile to upgrade to a single 24 port managed switch. They [don't have to cost that much](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F4WXW0O) these days.

New network map:

```
ISP1\
     \
      \
ISP2---   
        Untangle --- Switch --- Computers        
ISP3---
      /
     /
ISP4/
```

The bonus from all this setup is that you'll start to get all kinds of nice reports and statistics on use, and you can easily put a captive portal up in front of the workstations to enforce paid-for usage.

There are other products aside from Untangle that will do the same thing, but Untangle is pretty easy to setup for non-Network folk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that network working without any rewiring whatsoever, the simplest solution would be to configure all the routers with identical prefix for the LAN.

However it is important that you configure each router with a different IP address for their LAN interface. You also need to ensure that each of them use a different DHCP range.

I would not recommend using a /24 for the LAN. A shorter prefix will reduce the risk of running out of IP addresses on the DHCP servers.

For example on router `n` you could configure the LAN like this:

```
Network     10.4.0.0/20
IP          10.4.0.n
DHCP range  10.4.n.0 - 10.4.n.255
```

This is however not going to balance the traffic perfectly between the routers. If the DHCP servers on the routers have the necessary features, you can configure them to only allow certain MAC addresses to use them and balance the clients across the routers that way. Alternatively you can configure the gateway address manually on each client machine.

If you are willing to rewire the network a lot of other configurations are possible. Listing all the possibilities would exceed the maximum length of answers permitted on this site.